# 301 Redirect Magento System URLs to SEF version

Tags: magento-1.7, url-rewrite, seo

I'm struggling to find a solution to permanently redirect Magento's system product URLs, that look like this `http://domain.com/catalog/product/view/id/473`. My goal is to automatically redirect them to their search engine friendly version: `http://domain.com/blue-widget.html`

I checked my system settings and made sure that `Use Web Server Rewrites` is set to yes in Under `System > Configuration > General > Web > Search Engine Optimization`, but for some reason the redirect is not working. [Example URL](http://rvpartsuniverse.com/catalog/product/view/id/473)

Note that I'm running Magento 1.7

Answer (score 1):

Is the URL Key under `Catalog->Manage Products->Product set` ?
If this is set, there should be an entry in Catalog->URL Rewrite Management with Request

> Path =  catalog/product/view/id/473 and Target Path = catalog/product/view/id/473

Comment: So the URL key is set, but there the URL Rewrite Management entry you referred to doesn't exist...